# Expanding/resolving variable inside single quotes in zsh alias function

Tags: zsh, zsh-alias

I have a nice one-liner that I want to create an alias of. An instance of that one-liner looks like the following:

```
less +G $(find /var/logs -name 'service-output.root*' -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f2- -d' ')
```

Here it looks into the `/var/logs/` directory, does prefix matching for all files starting with `service-output.root` and opens the latest with `less`.

The alias I want to create should get the directory and the prefix regex as arguments, thus I came up with the following alias function

```
function l-log {
  if [[ ! ${#} -eq 2 ]] || [[ ! -d ${1} ]]; then
    echo "Usage: ${0} <dir> <regex>"
    return 1
  fi
  local DIR=${1}
  local FILE_REGEX=${2}

 find ${DIR} -name '${FILE_REGEX}' -printf '%T@ %p\\n' | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f2- -d' '
}
```

The problem is that this does not work.

```
$ l-log /var/logs/ service-output.root*
zsh: no matches found: service-output.root*
```

I have enabled function debugging

```
$ functions -t l-log
```

and tinkering a bit it seems that the problem is about variable `${FILE_REGEX}` not being properly expanded because it is single quoted (and it has to be single quoted)

```
$ l-log /apollo/var/logs/ apollo-update.root                                                                                                                                                                           1 ↵
+l-log:1> [[ ! 2 -eq 2 ]]
+l-log:1> [[ ! -d /apollo/var/logs/ ]]
+l-log:5> local DIR=/apollo/var/logs/
+l-log:6> local FILE_REGEX=apollo-update.root
+l-log:13> find /apollo/var/logs/ -name '${FILE_REGEX}' -printf '%T@ %p\\n'
+l-log:13> sort -n
+l-log:13> tail -1
+l-log:13> cut -f2- '-d '
```

I have tried several things like double quoting the variables, escaping single and double quotes, using double double (!) quotes (`""${FILE_REGEX}""`) and back ticking (`) but I haven't managed to get `+l-log:13>` above to become `find /apollo/var/logs/ -name 'service-output.root*' -printf '%T@ %p\\n'`

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things happening here.

- Minor point: You've created a function (which is great!), not an 'alias function'. Aliases are a different thing.
- Invoking a function with an argument containing a wildcard  needs special handling, or `zsh` will try to expand / glob the wildcard before it even gets to the function - that's where the `zsh: no matches found` message is coming from. Some ways to call the function:

  - option 1, quoting: `l-log /var/logs/ 'service-output.root*'`
  - option 2, escaping: `l-log /var/logs/ service-output.root\*`
  - option 3, noglob: `noglob l-log /var/logs/ service-output.root*`
- You do NOT need the single quotes in the call to `find`. Use `${FILE_REGEX}`.

The last part can be a bit confusing, since wildcards usually need to be quoted when calling `find`. But here the wildcard is contained in a variable, so `zsh` is not going to do any globbing unless you specifically ask for that.  The single quotes are preventing the variable `$FILE_REGEX` from being expanded, and you need that to occur.

---

BTW, you can do this kind of operation without `find`, using just `zsh`. Here's one option:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
llogBase() {
  local pattern=${1:?}/**/${2:?}(om[1])
  less -- ${~pattern}
}
```

Some notes on the parts:

- `pattern=${1:?}/**/${2:?}(om[1])` - this builds a glob pattern that we'll use in the next operation.

  - `.../**/...` - uses the [recursive glob](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Recursive-Globbing) operator `**/` to traverse the directory tree, similar to `find`.
  - `${1:?}` - substitutes the directory name supplied by the caller as the first parameter. With the [`${ :?}` expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion), this will print an error message and exit the function if the parameter is empty.
  - `${2:?}` - substitutes the second parameter, the filename wildcard pattern.
  - `(om)` - a [glob qualifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers). This asks the shell to sort `(o)` the results by modification time `(m)`, with the most recent file listed first.
  - `([1])` - another glob qualifier that selects which items to include. In this case the result will have at most one filename; with the `(om)` qualifier it will be the most recent matching file.
- `less -- ${~pattern}` - expands the pattern and calls `less`.

  - `${~pattern}` - expands to the contents of the `pattern` variable. Since it is a [`${~...}` expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-GLOB_005fSUBST_002c-toggle), the shell then performs globbing with the resulting string, and substitutes the single filename that matches the pattern (if one exists).
  - `less -- <filename>` - calls `less` to display the file. The `--` is a guard against [filenames that may start with `-`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/590210).
- `zsh` allows expansions to be nested, so the whole thing could be one slightly cryptic line: `less -- ${~:-${1:?}/**/${2:?}(om[1])}`.

This function can now be used to search for a file, but the wildcard will need to quoted or escaped as described above, e.g.:

```bash
llogBase /var/logs 'service-output.root*'
```

To avoid quoting patterns for this command, we can use an `alias` to always add the `noglob` precommand modifier:

```bash
alias llog='noglob llogBase'
```

Calling it with the alias:

```bash
llog /var/logs service-output.root*
```

Comment: Perfect answer! Some follow-ups for my understanding:
A) what is the benefit of having this `function` and then `alias` pattern you use? I understand that the two are different concepts but in practice are there downsides calling the `function` directly instead of creating an `alias` for it?
B) what does those `${1:?}`/`${2:?}` do?
C) what does the `~` do inside `${~pattern}`?
D) what does `--` mean in the `less` command

Comment: @VassilisMoustakas - I added some notes.